# Is there a way to get directory's actual path in wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to bind a property to a directory's id path. Is there a way to get the directory's actual path from a directory id or somehow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Directory element  Id attribute in WiX becomes the [Directory Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295(v=vs.85).aspx) Directory column in the build Windows Installer MSI database.   During installation, directory resolution is performed by the [CostFinalize Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368048(v=vs.85).aspx).  After this point you can Using a [Directory Property in a Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372403(v=vs.85).aspx).

> The directories in the Directory table specify the layout of an
>   installation. When the Windows Installer resolves these directories
>   during the CostFinalize action, the keys in the Directory table become
>   properties set to directory paths. The installer also always sets a
>   number of standard System Folder Properties to system folder paths.

For example in a RegistryValue element you could give a value of  `[INSTALLLOCATION]`.

Comment: Can Directory be referenced in property?

Comment: After CostFinalize, directory keys essentially are properties.  The difference is it takes a Type 35 custom action instead of a Type 51 custom action to change them.